# How to specify Column item offset in Jetpack Compose (Like ItemDecoration in RecyclerView)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working with a Jetpack Compose Column;
Same as for the stickyHeaders, I need to define a "stickyFooter" for the same item.
So: When the item is inside the screen, it scrolls with other items normally; If the item would leave the screen from top, it must act as stickyHeader; If the item would leave the screen from bottom, it should act as "stickyFooter".

I need something to implement this behavior.
Below, the code i wrote for RecyclerView that does this exact thing:

```
class StickyControlsItemDecoration : ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val viewType = parent.adapter?.getItemViewType(position) ?: 0

        if (!viewType.isSticky()) {
            return
        }

        parent.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _ ->
            val topMaxPosition = parent.height - view.height - parent.paddingBottom
            val itemTop = view.top.toFloat() + view.marginBottom

            when {
                itemTop > topMaxPosition -> {
                    view.translationY = topMaxPosition - itemTop
                }
                itemTop < 0 -> {
                    view.translationY = -itemTop
                }
                else -> {
                    view.translationY = 0f
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with measurable Layout, but it doesn't work on scroll.

```
Layout(
    content = {/*THINGS*/}
) { measurables, constraints ->
    /*apparently useless code*/
}
```

Comment: I think this should help: https://manavtamboli.medium.com/infinite-list-paged-list-in-jetpack-compose-b10fc7e74768

Comment: I suggest you creating a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128), even if you came up with some solution it'll be less performant than `LazyColumn` or too huge to maintain(e.g. if you take `LazyColumn` source code as the base).

Comment: I don't think it can be requested as a feature, because it is a very special case and of dubious utility